# Listing files with Paramiko returning UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I'm trying to download files from SFTP using Paramiko and Python.
I didn't find any solution to avoid the unicode error.

It works using the `sftp.get()` method but I must filter filenames first because they are dynamic.

```
for entry in sftp.listdir_attr(path):
    mode = entry.st_mode
    if S_ISREG(mode) and "erapsuspj" in entry.filename:
        list_rep.append(entry.filename)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "....\getRep.py", line 49, in <module>
    for entry in sftp.listdir_attr(path):
  File "....\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 254, in listdir_attr
    filename = msg.get_text()
  File "....\site-packages\paramiko\message.py", line 184, in get_text
    return u(self.get_string())
  File "....\site-packages\paramiko\util.py", line 333, in u
    return s.decode(encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 7: invalid continuation byte
```

Any ideas? Thanks, Alex

Answer (score 1):

In SFTP, all strings are UTF-8. It seems that your SFTP server is broken and is sending file names in other encoding.

There are no easy solutions. Paramiko (rightfully) does not allow you to change the encoding it uses to decode the filenames.

- You can implement, what `listdir_attr` does, on your own, except for the UTF-8 decoding. Instead of the `msg.get_text()`, call `msg.get_string().decode(actual_encoding)`.
- Or patch the `u()` function to use another encoding.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I'm pretty sure almost all files are in UTF-8.
Is there a way to ignore all files that gives an error to make this work ?

Comment: What do you mean by *"almost all files are in UTF-8"*? This is not about file *contents*. It's about file *names*. + I've already posted in my answer what you can do about it.

Comment: I meant filename yes, wasn't precise enough.
No way to iterate through sftp files avoiding names? Not possible to get files by index on the sftp dir? I'll try to modify the function then, thks.

Comment: How can only some file names be in certain encoding? Encoding is a property of a file system, not of individual file names. Anyway, the SFTP server has to use UTF-8 encoding, no matter what encoding the underlying file system uses. + I do not understand why you think I'd propose you more complicated solution, if there was easier one.